# MVC 4 Change Application Name of Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am using the default setup for MVC 4 project.

I have 2 projects, one for a shop front and another for an admin area.
I want to specify the application name of each of these to be different so I can log into my admin area and shopfront independently even though both must run from the same database.

Ideally, I want to keep on using the simple membership provider.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SimpleMembership doesn't have application name like regular Membership Provider.**

However, you can store all users in same database, and restrict access by roles.

In other words, those who login to/access Admin site must have admin role assigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different domains like admin.myshop.com and shop.myshop.com the auth cookie isn't shared, so you can be logged in in both with different account

Answer (score 0):

The Application Name of a provider can be set in your `Web.config`, like so:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" applicationName="YourApplicationName" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, better approach will be just to define needed amount of specific roles for your admin project.